# Tensor product is commutative on commutative algebra

Tags: commutative-algebra, modules, tensor-products

I need to prove that the tensor product of $A-$modules is commutative, ie:

> $M\otimes_AN\simeq N\otimes_AM.$

I tried to construct an isomorphism $\varphi $ of kind $ m\otimes n\mapsto n\otimes m$, but I think this is not an homomorphism, because:

$\varphi(m\otimes n+m'\otimes n')=\varphi((m+m')\otimes (n+n'))\\
\qquad\qquad\qquad\quad\quad =(n+n')\otimes (m+m')\\
\qquad\qquad\qquad\quad\quad=n\otimes m+n'\otimes m+n\otimes m'+n'\otimes m'\\
\qquad\qquad\qquad\quad\quad\neq n\otimes m+n'\otimes m'=\varphi(m\otimes n)+\varphi(m'\otimes n').$

I thank any ideia.

Comment: $$(m+m')\otimes (n+n')=m\otimes n+m\otimes n'+m'\otimes n+m'\otimes n'\ne m\otimes n+m'\otimes n'$$ in general.

Comment: Really. So, I'm thinking if $\varphi$ is in fact an homomorphism? But how can I write the property? Thank you.

Comment: $M\otimes_A N$ and $N\otimes_A M$ are objects representing the functors of bilinear maps from $M\times N$ and $N\times M$ respectively. These functors are naturally isomorphic...

Comment: Thank you, Sir.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This equation is wrong: $ φ(m⊗n+m′⊗n′)=φ((m+m′)⊗(n+n′))$. The tensor product is bilinear.

Comment: $(m+m')\otimes(n+n')=m\otimes(n+n')+m'\otimes(n+n')=m\otimes n+m\otimes n'+m'\otimes n +m'\otimes n'$, really...! Many thanks. So, $\varphi$ is in fact an homomorphism? How can I write the property? Thank you.